# How to update filed when user type something in field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a field with this code

```
<tr><td> <input type="text" value="good"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'good') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='good'}" name="name" maxlength="254" class="required" /></td></tr>
```

when user click on field then we have clear and empty field.and if user put field empty we write back this `good` value.but that's not what I want, I am looking for some way like user registration form in facebook then if user type a character we clear value and if user keep field empty we will fill in this field with default value..can someone help me with this javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `placeholder` attribute for that

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="good" name="name" maxlength="254" class="required" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

This shows as long as the user hasn't input text, but it doesn't change the `value` attribute.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LTzf8/1/) for testing.

Comment: is placeholder html 5 or can be used on html 4 too

Comment: @HiDd3N `placeholder` is HTML5 only.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your input to:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="good" placeholder="good" name="name" maxlength="254" class="required defaultText" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And add some jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".defaultText").focus(function(srcc) {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].placeholder) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $(".defaultText").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val($(this)[0].placeholder);
        }
    });

    $(".defaultText").blur();        
});
```

The `defaultText` style class, is used to select the html elements, and the `placeholder` in the element is defining the default value for it.

**Edit:** Changed `title` for `placeholder`, this way it will be compatible with html5 or previous

[Example from here.](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/default_text_fields_using_simple_jquery_trick.aspx)

Comment: I'd suggest using defaultValue instead of adding a title attribute.

such as: $(this).get(0).defaultValue;

Answer (score 1):

If placeholder attributes aren't viable you could use the onkeydown event instead of onfocus.